# Find two numbers from a list that add up to a specific number

Tags: python, for-loop, permutation

This is super bad and messy, I am new to this, please help me.

Basically, I was trying to find two numbers from a list that add up to a target number.

I have set up an example with `lst = [2, 4, 6, 10]` and a target value of `target = 8`. The answer in this example would be `(2, 6)` and `(6, 2)`.

Below is my code but it is long and ugly and I am sure there is a better way of doing it. Can you please see how I can improve from my code below?

```
from itertools import product, permutations

numbers = [2, 4, 6, 10]
target_number = 8

two_nums = (list(permutations(numbers, 2)))
print(two_nums)

result1 = (two_nums[0][0] + two_nums[0][1])
result2 = (two_nums[1][0] + two_nums[1][1])
result3 = (two_nums[2][0] + two_nums[2][1])
result4 = (two_nums[3][0] + two_nums[3][1])
result5 = (two_nums[4][0] + two_nums[4][1])
result6 = (two_nums[5][0] + two_nums[5][1])
result7 = (two_nums[6][0] + two_nums[6][1])
result8 = (two_nums[7][0] + two_nums[7][1])
result9 = (two_nums[8][0] + two_nums[8][1])
result10 = (two_nums[9][0] + two_nums[9][1])

my_list = (result1, result2, result3, result4, result5, result6, result7, result8, result9, result10)
print (my_list)

for i in my_list:
  if i == 8:
print ("Here it is:" + str(i))
```

Comment: would `4` and `4` be a solution in your example?

Comment: Isn't this more suitable for [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, yes, but in this case, I try not to added by its number.

Comment: @sophros, Thanks for providing me useful links, they look very helpful!

Comment: Your code is almost completely specific to problem. What if the list were of a different length? Your code wouldn't work. And naming a bunch of specific variables like that is almost never a good idea. You need to do it in an organised, general way. To get you started, try something like: `for a, b in permutations(numbers, 2):`. By the way: it's more appropriate to use combinations here, because the order of summands doesn't matter.

Comment: @Denziloe, you're right... I am so lost. Thank you for the [for a, b in permutations(numbers, 2)] code suggestion!

Comment: Don't worry, this is a common mistake, and trying to do something with `permutations` (or combinations) as you did is actually quite a nice Pythonic approach with a lot of new people wouldn't consider. For future reference (not necessarily for this problem), the proper way of making lots of variables like that involves making a list called e.g. `result` and then putting the values in `result[0]`, `result[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For every number on the list, you can look for his complementary (number that when added to the previous one would give the required `target` sum). If it exists, get the pair and exit, otherwise move on.

This would look like the following:

```
numbers = [2, 4, 6, 10]
target_number = 8

for i, number in enumerate(numbers[:-1]):  # note 1
    complementary = target_number - number
    if complementary in numbers[i+1:]:  # note 2
        print("Solution Found: {} and {}".format(number, complementary))
        break
else:  # note 3
    print("No solutions exist")
```

which produces:

```
Solution Found: 2 and 6
```

---

Notes:

1. You do not have to check the last number; if there was a pair you would have already found it by then.
2. Notice that the membership check (which is quite costly in lists) is optimized since it considers the slice `numbers[i+1:]` only. The previous numbers have been checked already. A positive side-effect of the slicing is that the existence of e.g., one `4` in the list, does not give a pair for a target value of `8`.
3. This is an excellent setup to explain the miss-understood and often confusing use of `else` in `for`-loops. The `else` triggers only if the loop was not abruptly ended by a `break`.

---

---

If the e.g., `4` - `4` solution is acceptable to you even when having a **single** `4` in the list you can modify as follows:

```
numbers = [2, 4, 6, 10]
target_number = 8

for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    complementary = target_number - number
    if complementary in numbers[i:]:
        print("Solution Found: {} and {}".format(number, complementary))
        break
else:
    print("No solutions exist")
```

Comment: This is incredible, let me take some time to absorb, thank you so much! 
and thank you for giving me the 4-4 solution too.

Comment: @moomoochen Have fun absorbing and if any questions arise I will be happy to answer them. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension will work well here.  Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations

numbers = [2, 4, 6, 10]
target_number = 8

solutions = [pair for pair in permutations(numbers, 2) if sum(pair) == 8]
print('Solutions:', solutions)
```

Basically, this list comprehension looks at all the pairs that `permutations(numbers, 2)` returns, but only keeps the ones whose total sum equals 8.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in one line with list comprehension like below:

```
from itertools import permutations

numbers = [2, 4, 6, 10]
target_number = 8
two_nums = (list(permutations(numbers, 2)))

result=[i for i in two_nums if i[0]+i[1] == target_number]
```

> [(2,6) , (6,2)]

Comment: This is perhaps the least efficient way to do this, requiring O(n^2) of additional space.

Comment: @StevenW.Klassen True! Just seemed the most approachable by a someone new to python

Answer (score 1):

The simplest general way to do this is to iterate over your list and for each item iterate over the rest of the list to see if it adds up to the target value. The downside of this is it is an O(n^2) operation. I don't know off the top of my head if there is a more efficient solution. I'm not 100% sure my syntax is correct, but it should look something like the following:

```
done = False
for i, val in enumerate(numbers):
    if val >= target_number:
        continue
    for j, val2 in enumerate(numbers, i+1):
        if val + val2 == target_number:
            print ("Here it is: " + str(i) + "," + str(j))
            done = True
            break
    if done:
        break
```

Of course you should create this as a function that returns your result instead of just printing it. That would remove the need for the "done" variable.

Comment: I'll comment on my own solution that the one presented by @kounis is slightly better. It isn't more efficient (it is doing the same thing as my code), but it is doing it more elegantly and compactly (in terms of the amount of code). It also handles negative numbers whereas mine does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find the answer for multiple integers with a long list that has duplicate values, I would recommend using frozenset. The "checked" answer will only get the first answer and then stop.

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)
target = 17

def adds_to_target(base_list, target):
    return_list = []
    for i in range(len(base_list)):
        return_list.extend([list((base_list[i], b)) for b in base_list if (base_list[i] + b)==target])
    return set(map(frozenset, return_list))

# sample output
{frozenset({7, 10}),
 frozenset({4, 13}),
 frozenset({8, 9}),
 frozenset({5, 12}),
 frozenset({2, 15}),
 frozenset({3, 14}),
 frozenset({0, 17}),
 frozenset({1, 16}),
 frozenset({6, 11})}
```

1) In the first for loop, lists containing two integers that sum to the target value are added to "return_list" i.e. a list of lists is created.

2) Then frozenset takes out all duplicate pairs.

```
%timeit adds_to_target(numbers, target_number)
# 312 ms ± 8.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to do this efficiently without itertools -

```
numbers = [1,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,1]
target = 5
number_dict = {}
pairs = []
for num in numbers:
    number_dict[num] = number_dict.get(num, 0) + 1
    complement = target - num
    if complement in number_dict.keys():
        pairs.append((num, complement))
        number_dict.pop(num)
        number_dict.pop(complement)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is this simple :)

```
def func(array, target):
    flag = 0;
    for x in array:
        for y in array:
            if (target-x) == y and x != y:
                print(x,y)
                flag = 1
                break
        if flag ==1:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

Filename = "D:\\python interview\\test.txt"
wordcount_dict = dict()
#input("Enter Filename:") 

list_ = [1,2,4,6,8]
num = 10

for number in list_:
    num_add = number
    for number_ in list_:
        if number_ + num_add == num and number_ != num_add :
            print(number_ , num_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [2, 4, 6, 10]
t = 8

for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i, len(l)):
        if l[i]+l[j] == t and (l[i] != l[j]):
            print(l[i], l[j])
            print(l[j], l[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

n is the sum desired, L is the List. Basically you enter inside the loop and from that no to end of list iterate through the next loop. If L[i],L[j] indexes in list adds up to n and if L[i]!=L[j] print it.

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,9,8,5,10,20,30,6]
def two_no_summer(n,L):
     for i in range(0,len(L)):
         for j in range(i,len(L)):
             if (L[i]+L[j]==n) & (L[i]!=L[j]):
                  print(L[i],L[j])
```

Execution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu47x.jpg

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code

Comment: This will throw a syntax error as the indentation is incorrect

Comment: Rectified syntax, indentation and added descriptions. Hope it works now